# Search follows of user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got one **user** in table **users** with these fields:

> id = 1, name, lastname, photo, friendly_url

I got the table **followers** with these fields:

> user_id (1), follower_id

I got 'search', what the user write, and the *$id* of the **user followed**:

```
public function u_followers_search($id) {
  $_POST['search']
}
```

I want to search all the users that follow the **user $id** with the **$_POST['search']** and show these users...

Comment: please add your user and follower table model class and its relationship

Answer (score 0):

Sohel is right, it would help for you to post a lot more information. However, without that information it should be fairly straight forward assuming you have the models built out. Its a fairly simple query:

`$follower_id = $_POST['search'];
 $users = User::where('follower_id', $follower_id)->get();`